# Automatic disposal of ko postbox subscriptons

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-postbox

I have a single page app that consists of 2 main pieces:

```
1.-A top bar that has dynamic content(there is a shopping cart)
2.-A dynamic component that gets loaded based on the url.
```

A few times the components use postbox in order to communicate, the problem is that once the component itself is disposed the subscriptions created inside **are not**. I know I can manually add a dispose function to each component and then inside, dispose the subscriptions, **but is there a way to do this in an automated way for all components?**

I do know how to loop all properties and check if they are subscriptions, but I need a way to somehow attach this behavior to all components without manually attaching this dispose function to all of them.

I know postbox comes with a reset method I can call inside my routing library but I do not want to do that because then the top bar will lose its subscriptions too.

To give you some perspective, this is how the main index page looks like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Participant Dashboard</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <!-- styles -->
    <link href="../css/bs3/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/bs3/override-bs3.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="../scripts/global/requireConfig.js"></script>
    <script data-main="../consumer/scripts/require-config" src="../scripts/require.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<top-bar params="routeParams:currentPageArguments"></top-bar>

<div data-bind="component: { name: currentPage, params: currentPageArguments }">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

This is my custom component loader:

```js
    function registerConventionLoader() {
        var koNamingConventionLoader = {
            getConfig: function (name, callback) {
                var widgetName;
                var widgetConfig = common.findComponentConfig(name);
                if (widgetConfig != null) {
                    widgetName = name.substr(widgetConfig.Prefix.length);
                    var widgetNamePascalCase = common.toPascalCase(widgetName);
                    var filePath = widgetConfig.Path;
                    var viewModelConfig = {require: filePath + widgetNamePascalCase};
                    var templateConfig = {require: "text!" + filePath + widgetNamePascalCase + '.html'};

                    callback({viewModel: viewModelConfig, template: templateConfig});
                }
                else {
                    
                    callback(null);
                }
            }
        };
        ko.components.loaders.push(koNamingConventionLoader);
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found it!
I had to get the viewmodel from require, then attach the dispose function and finally pass it in the callback:
Thanks @user3297291 for guiding me in the correct direction

```js
var koNamingConventionLoader = {
            getConfig: function (name, callback) {
               
                var widgetName;
                var widgetConfig = common.findComponentConfig(name);
                
                if (widgetConfig != null) {
                    widgetName = name.substr(widgetConfig.Prefix.length);
                    var widgetNamePascalCase = common.toPascalCase(widgetName);
                    var filePath = widgetConfig.Path;
                    
                    require([filePath + widgetNamePascalCase], function (mainViewModel) {
                        mainViewModel.prototype.dispose = function () {
                            var self = this;
                            for (var property in self) {
                                if (Boolean(self[property]) && typeof self[property].dispose === "function") {
                                    
                                    self[property].dispose();
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        
                        var templateConfig = {require: "text!" + filePath + widgetNamePascalCase + '.html'};

                        callback({viewModel: mainViewModel, template: templateConfig});
                    });
                }
                else {
                    
                    console.log("widget name not resolved", name);
                    callback(null);
                }
            }
        };
        ko.components.loaders.push(koNamingConventionLoader);
    }
```

Comment: Why the downvote? is there something wrong with this solution?

Answer (score 2):

### Already implemented behavior

The postbox plugin adds a `dispose` method to your observables to dispose any dependencies it created.

> The dispose function removes all the subscriptions that an observable has on any topic as well as all the subscriptions used to automatically publish changes to the observable.
>
> This function is attached to the observable when publishOn, subscribeTo or syncWith is called.
>
> <sub>Source: [postbox github docs](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox)</sub>

If your component's viewmodel has a `dispose` method, knockout will call it when removing the component.

> Optionally, your viewmodel class may have a `dispose` function. If implemented, Knockout will call this whenever the component is being torn down and removed from the DOM
>
> <sub>Source: [component-binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-binding.html#disposal-and-memory-management)</sub>

### The custom disposal logic

Knowing these two library/plugin behaviors, we can conclude that this general idea should do the trick:

```
MyCustomComponent.prototype.dispose = function() {
  /* call `.dispose` on all properties that support it */
};
```

The only code left we'll have to write is the commented out part:

- Loop over a viewmodel's properties
- Check if they support a `dispose` method
- Call it if they do

Which boils down to:

```
MyCustomComponent.prototype.dispose = function() {
  var self = this;
  var propNames = Object.keys(this);

  propNames.forEach(function(key) { // Loop over vm's properties
    var val = self[key];

    if (typeof val.dispose === "function") { // Check of dispose implementation
      val.dispose(); // call dispose
    }
  });
};
```

Or, in a different style:

```
MyCustomComponent.prototype.dispose = function() {
  Object
    .keys(this)
    .filter(k => typeof this[k] === "function")
    .forEach(k => this[k]());
};
```

### Making sure *all* components implement the disposal logic

I'd highly recommend using a "regular" inheritance or composition pattern to make sure all your components implement this feature.

*Al though this forces you to edit all of your components, **it also explicitly shows other readers/future you the implemented behavior**.*

If you really want to go wild, you could overwrite the component engine's `register` method to add the method to the vm upon instantiation, but I wouldn't recommend it:

```
var _register = ko.components.register;
ko.components.register = function(name, opts) {
  var ogVM = opts.viewmodel;
  opts.viewmodel = function(params) {
     ogVM.call(this, params);
     this.dispose = function() { /* ... */ }
  }
  return _register(name, opts);
};
```

Comment: Thanks @user3297291. I have provided a better description of what I want, I know how to traverse all properties and check if there are subscriptions, what I do not know is if there is a way to automatically attach this functions to all components without doing it manually.

Comment: You use a regular inheritance or composition pattern to make sure the `dispose` method is added to the viewmodel... Would it help if I gave you an example?

Comment: Thanks again!, I tried this approach but I think I forgot to mention something important, I am using a custom component loader, when I try your solution to intercept the register function it seems like it is never executed.

Comment: i believe your "Loop over a viewmodel's properties" should be read as: "Deep traverse the ViewModel", what is your opinion about that?